# Callback function argument which is required for wp_list_comments ()

Tags: comments

## comments.php

```
 <?php 
       $args=array(
         'type'=> 'comment',
         'callback'=>'my_comment_list',
        );
    ?>
    <ol class="comments-list">
     <?php wp_list_comments($args) ?>
    </ol>
```

## function.php

```
function my_comment_list($comment,$arg,$depth){

}
```

When trying to create a callback function called my_comment_list, it looks like I need three types of arguments for the callback function, `$ comment, $ arg, $ depth`,

My question is:

**How do you know you need these arguments for callback function?**
and **Where do you get detailed explanations of arguments, etc.?**

I usually refer to the below link in Wordpress template tags and functions, but It was not there...

[Wordpress Developer Resource](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_comments/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_list_comments()` uses [`Walker_Comment`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_comment/) class to render the output.

See `Walker_Comment->start_el()` method for callback argument:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_comment/start_el/

And `Walker_Comment->end_el()` method for end-callback argument:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_comment/end_el/